body_add_table() will cause errors
library(officer)
doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_table(doc, iris, style = "table_template")
doc

issues

Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "style_name", value = character(0)) :
replacement has 0 rows, data has 755

How to solve this issue? The above codes are sample code from officer package.

The problem comes from trying to visualize the document using the doc command.
It disappears if you use:
library(officer)
doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_table(doc, iris, style = "table_template")
print(doc, target = "test.docx")

Created on 2024-05-16 with reprex v2.1.0
